# IronPython "LookupError: unknown encoding: hex"

Tags: json, import, ironpython

When I try to "import simplejson" (or something that depends on it) in [IronPython 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython), I get "LookupError: unknown encoding: hex". How do I make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround for this is to import the hex codec manually before attempting to import the broken dependency:

```
from encodings import hex_codec
```

The issue is being [tracked by IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=20634), but so far, they claim it's a bug in the standard Python library.

Comment: here is a link to the python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue9329 -- this may also be relevant for `LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, sblom. I think IronPython crew are right in saying its a bug in the standard library (or at least Freeze tool as of 2.7). Problem occurs with "frozen" programs if`from encodings import hex_codec` is not explicitly written in the script.

Sorry to 'necro-post', but this issue I feel was relevant, at least in regard to the Freeze tool.

Comment: cx_Frozen 4.0 (in ubuntu 11.10) has this error, cx_Frozen 4.3.2 doesn't has.